# C- Comparison operator instead of strcmp

Tags: c, string, strcmp

What will happen if I use comparison operators to compare strings instead of strcmp in C? Will it compare its ASCII value and return results?

Comment: Ok, what will be ASCII value of a string ?

Comment: "Will it compare its ASCII value and return results?" Assuming you meant "values", nope, that's what `strcmp` does ( If you're using the ascii character set ).

Comment: What did you find out yourself? What did your C book say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will compare the addresses of the two pointers.

so:

```
char* a = "hello";
char* b = "test";
char* c = "hello";
char* d = a;

a == d; // true
a == b; // false
a == c; // true or false, depending on the compiler's behavior.
```

The third example will be true if the compiler decides to recycle the actual string data for "hello", but it has no obligation to do so.

Comment: While you are right with the conclusion, these examples are badly choosen. `char *` is not the same as a string literal.

Comment: @Olaf, the question is about null-terminated strings, not string literals. I just happen to use string literals because 1) It makes for shorter examples, 2) it exposes how tricky it can get with string pooling.

Comment: A string is still not a pointer, but an array. And a string literal will be converted to a multibyte character sequence in translation phase 6 and a terminator is appended in phase 7. They are identical with respect to the string semantics (except for mutability, which is not relevant here).

Comment: strcmp, which is what this question is about, operates on null-terminated string pointers, not arrays. The fact that string arrays are implicitely convertible to char pointers is besides the point.

Comment: There are no "string pointers" in C. The functions take `char *`. Definitively not a "string array (which would be a `char [][]`. If you feel to answer questions about tutoring, at least be precise.

Comment: Thank you @Frank :)

Comment: _**"strcmp, which is what this question is about, operates on null-terminated string pointers"**_ I have never heard about null terminated pointers :). Can you explain what the **null terminated pointer** is and  give me one example of the **null terminated pointer**? Do another null terminated ponters exist? (for example double null terminated pointer)

Comment: @PeterJ, it's the string that's null-terminated, not the pointer.

Comment: @Frank - :) it was just a joke.